# Hibernate update table with same values without session.save or session.update

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate update table with same values without session.save or session.update

How can we load an object(a row from database) and save it back without changing anything any field values.

We need hibernate to issue an UPDATE query for that row with the same values it loaded.
We have a middleware between Hibernate and JDBC which alters the data while hibernate is doing the UPDATE.

We have tried session.replicate but it is removing all collections of that object.
i.e

```
class User{
        Set<Order> orders; //inversely mapped

    }
    class Order{
        User user;
    }

while doing session.replicate(user) it is issueing a following SQL

update ORDER set user=null where id=?
```

That means we are loosing all our relations.

session.save or session.update wont work as we are not changing the values before passing to hibernate.

Is there any other way of forcing hibernate to consider that all fields are modified, and it should update the database?

Comment: If you do not want to change the values why to fire the update? Or do you want to make your session object and DB objects in sync?

Comment: We have a middle-ware between Hibernate and JDBC which alters(encrypts and decrypts) the data while hibernate is doing the UPDATE and SELECT. We need this solution for existing unencrypted data. We first load and then save again, so while saving we encrypt it. But all this is hidden to hibernate so it does not know that values are changed.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement preflushListener to set all entities to altered and set `dynamicupdate="false"` for this class.

i think you can look at and extend one of:

```
DefaultFlushEventListener.java
DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java
```

Comment: Do I need to do session.replicate? or session.update? or anything else to make the above listener work?

Comment: only if the entities are not already attached to the session which is not the case when you loaded the object with the same session

Comment: Sorry for sounding stupid, I did not find any preflushlistener in documentation.